# Trivia: What is this symbol that AWS EC2 displays once you SSH into the machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Just really interested about this one, what the blazes is this ASCII art here?

```
$ ssh foo@$AWS_IP

Last login: Sat Mar 21 08:39:27 2015 from xx.xx.xx.xx

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|
```

I need it for my sanity.

Comment: Completely irrelevant question

Comment: Yeah, it is. I have my answer so please do feel free to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's ASCII art that says EC2. That stands for Elastic Compute Cloud

Comment: Ooh, now I do see it. Something must be wrong with my vision for not having recognized it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see it at first but after looking at all of the ones generated by http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=testall&f=Stampatello&t=EC2, I see it now.  It's sort of three dimensional with the left side of the characters missing.  Where else could this be answered if not on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your custom ones using utility figlet.
'showfigfonts' will show you what fonts are available, the one aws uses is named "standard"

We make custom banners like aws by ebextensions. ie create file .ebextension/000update-motd.config

```
commands:
  setup_banner:
    command: |
      yum erase -y update-motd
      unlink /etc/motd 
      amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
      yum-config-manager --enable epel
      yum install -y figlet
      # Add Motd as Beanstalk Environment Name
      echo `{"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }` | figlet -f standard > /etc/motd
      # Add warning disclaimer from your code ( optional )
      # cat /var/app/current/.platform/banner  >> /etc/motd  

    test: rpm --quiet -q update-motd  || [[ ! -f /etc/motd ]]
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: to install figlet on amazon linux 2 you need to do `sudo yum install amazon-linux-extras` then `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel`, only then is `sudo yum install figlet` working.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot banner generator can generate text with same look and feel. (See image attached)  [ https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/banner.txt/index.html ][Spring-boot Banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWZ2P.png)

Comment: This does not seems to answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The font is `Small Shadow` and you can generate them here: https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Small%20Shadow&t=EC2

The file to modify on the machine is in /etc/motd on Ubuntu.